# Mapping values to different values in list

Tags: python

The problem is to map a particular list in order to accumulate the time. A single change in digit accounts for 1 ms . However the clock resets after number 255.

```
list_val = [ 253 ,1,15,27,45,63,120,140,195,210,225,243,2,5,1]
```

The output should be like

```
new_list = [ 1 ,3,17,29,47,65,122,142,197,212,227,245,257,260,510].
```

Here is what I have tried

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(list_val)):
      if i == 0:
          new_list.append(1)
      elif list_val[i-1] < list_val[i] :
          new_list[i] =new_list.append(list_val[i] - list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
      elif list_val[i-1] > list_val[i] :
          new_list[i] = new_list.append(255 - list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
      else: #list_val[i-1] == list_val[i]:
          new_list[i] = new_list.append(255 + list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
```

The following is the error
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your syntax.

Calling the append method will add an element to the original list but it returns None. So you need to adjust your code as follows.

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(list_val)):
    if i == 0:
        new_list.append(1)
    elif list_val[i-1] < list_val[i] :
        new_list.append(list_val[i] - list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
        # you can replace new_list[i-1] with new_list[-1] if you choose to
    elif list_val[i-1] > list_val[i] :
        new_list.append(255 - list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
    else:
        new_list.append(255 + list_val[i-1] + new_list[i-1])
```

The result is

```
new_list = [1, 3, 17, 29, 47, 65, 122, 142, 197, 212, 227, 245, 257, 260, 510]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import numpy as np
list_val = [ 253 ,1,15,27,45,63,120,140,195,210,225,243,2,5,1]
new_list = np.cumsum(np.remainder(np.diff(list_val), 256))
```

Basically what happens is:

- first compute the differences `list_val[i] - list_val[i-1]` via the numpy diff function
- transform the differences into values between 0 and 255 by computing the remainder of each difference by division with 256 (in mathematical terms the modulo term)
- apply cumulative sum on the remainders

PS: I know the result is not *exactly* as what you gave as the expected output, but I struggle a bit to understand why the first 1 ms is statically always set in.

Comment: well your explanation is interesting but this is not what I wanted. Anyways thanks!